# How to unit test function that has coroutine `GlobalScope.launch`

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have this function

```
    override fun trackEvent(trackingData: TrackingData) {
        trackingData.eventsList()
    }
```

And I could have my test as below.

```
    @Test
    fun `My Test`() {
        // When
        myObject.trackEvent(myTrackingMock)

        // Then
        verify(myTrackingMock, times(1)).eventsList()
    }
```

However, if I make it into a

```
    override fun trackEvent(trackingData: TrackingData) {
        GlobalScope.launch{
            trackingData.eventsList()
        }
    }
```

How could I still get my test running? (i.e. can make the `launch` Synchronous?)

Answer (score 4):

I created my own `CoroutineScope` and pass in (e.g. `CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)` as a variable `myScope`)

Then have my function

```
    override fun trackEvent(trackingData: TrackingData) {
        myScope.launch{
            trackingData.eventsList()
        }
    }
```

Then in my test I mock the scope by create a `blockCoroutineScope` as below.

```
   class BlockCoroutineDispatcher : CoroutineDispatcher() {
        override fun dispatch(context: CoroutineContext, block: Runnable) {
            block.run()
        }
    }

    private val blockCoroutineScope = CoroutineScope(BlockCoroutineDispatcher())
```

For my test, I'll pass the `blockCoroutineScope` in instead as `myScope`. Then the test is executed with `launch` as a blocking operation.

Comment: You can improve this if you follow Kotlin guys' advice and make `trackEvent` an extension on `CoroutineScope`: `fun CoroutineScope.trackEvent(...)`. For example, the `launch` block has a `CoroutineScope` as its receiver, so if you call `trackEvent` inside it, you automatically pass that scope to it. And for a unit test, surround it with a `runBlocking`, which also has `CoroutineScope` as the receiver.

Answer (score 3):

To approach the answer, try asking a related question: "How would I unit-test a function that has

```
Thread { trackingData.eventsList() }
```

in it?"

Your only hope is running a loop that repeatedly checks the expected condition, for some period time, until giving up and declaring the test failed.

When you wrote `GlobalScope.launch`, you waived your interest in Kotlin's structured concurrency, so you'll have to resort to unstructured and non-deterministic approaches of testing.

Probably the best recourse is to rewrite your code to use a scope under your control.

Comment: Thanks @MarkoTopolnik. I have done so, and it's working now as per my below answer

Answer (score 0):

I refactored my method to

```
suspend fun deleteThing(serial: String): String? = coroutineScope {
```

This way, I can launch coroutines with `launch`

```
val jobs = mutableListOf<Job>()
var certDeleteError: String? = null

certs.forEach { certArn ->
    val job = launch {
        deleteCert(certArn, serial)?.let { error ->
            jobs.forEach { it.cancel() }
            certDeleteError = error
        }
    }
    jobs.add(job)
}

jobs.joinAll()
```

For the test, I can then just use `runTest` and it runs all of the coroutines synchronously

```
    @Test
    fun successfullyDeletes2Certs() = runTest {
        aws.deleteThing("s1")
```

Now you just need to mind your context where you are calling the `deleteThing` function. For me, it was a ktor request, so I could just call `launch` there also.

```
    delete("vehicles/{vehicle-serial}/") {
        launch {
            aws.deleteThing(serial)
        }
    }
```